# overwrite package struct in systemverilog design

Tags: system-verilog

I try to overwrite package struct by declare another packad struct outside the module
and overwrite it as parameter
Here is RTL code.

Top Module

```
module test_top 
#()
();

//Module A
A#()
u0
();


//Module B
B#()
u1
(); 

endmodule
```

Module A

```
module A 
#()
();

typedef struct packed
{
 logic [31:0]    addr    ;       
 logic [3:0]     tag     ;       
} a_cmd_t;

target
#(
  .CNT    (4),
  .CMD_T  (a_cmd_t   )   
)
u0
(
 .cmd() 
); 

endmodule
```

Module B

```
module B 
#(
)
(
);

typedef struct packed
{
 logic [31:0]    addr    ;       
 logic [7:0]     tag     ;       
} b_cmd_t;

target
#(
   .CNT(5),         
   .CMD_T (b_cmd_t) 
)
u0
(
  .cmd() 
);

endmodule
```

Module Target

```
module target
import target_pkg::*;
 #(
 parameter CNT = 1,             
 parameter type CMD_T     = target_cmd_t      
)
(
 output CMD_T cmd
);

localparam WIDTH = $bits(cmd.tag);  
localparam ZERO_FILL_WIDTH = (WIDTH - CNT);

wire [ZERO_FILL_WIDTH-1:0] test;
assign test = {ZERO_FILL_WIDTH{1'b0}};

endmodule
```

Package

```
package target_pkg;

typedef struct packed
{
 logic [31:0]   addr  ;       
 logic [7:0]    tag   ; 
} target_cmd_t;

endpackage
```

But when I do compile (w/ VCS) , it seems the number can not overwrote as my expectation
Because I will get compile error as following:

```
Error-[ZMMCM] Zero multiconcat multiplier
~/target.sv, 15
"{ZERO_FILL_WIDTH {1'b0}}"
  Zero multiconcat multiplier cannot be used in this context. (Target as 
  above)
  A replication with a zero replication constant is considered to have a size 
  of zero and is ignored. Such a replication shall appear only within a 
  concatenation in which at least one of the operands of the concatenation has
  a positive size.
  Please use -error=noZMMCM to get around this error.
  Instance stack trace:
      target#(4, a_cmd_t, , )   
~/A.sv, 21
      A#()   
~/test_top.sv, 14
      test_top  
~/test_top.sv, 2
  

Error-[NMCM] Negative multiconcat multiplier
~/target.sv, 15
  Multiconcat multiplier cannot be negative value.
  Source info: {ZERO_FILL_WIDTH {1'b0}}
  Instance stack trace:
      target#(5, b_cmd_t, , )   
~/B.sv, 23
      B#()   
~/test_top.sv, 21
      test_top  
~/test_top.sv, 2
  Please refer LRM(1364-2005) section 5.1.14.
```

For the first error message "zero multiconcat multiplier" I think it's reasonable, because for module A (hierarchy:test_top.u0.u0)
parameter CNT is 4, WIDTH = $bits(cmd.tag) = 4
So the parameter ZERO_FILL_WIDTH= (WIDTH - CNT) = 0.

But for the other error message "Negative multiconcat multiplier"
which come from module B (hierarchy:test_top.u1.u0) is unreasonable for me.
because for module B (hierarchy:test_top.u1.u0)
parameter CNT is 5, `WIDTH = $bits(cmd.tag)` = 8
So the parameter ZERO_FILL_WIDTH= (WIDTH - CNT) = 3 is a positive value.

I try to modify Module B like this:

```
module B 
#(
)
(
);

typedef struct packed
{
 logic [31:0]    addr    ;       
 logic [7:0]     tag     ;       
} b_cmd_t;

target
#(
   .CNT(3),         
   .CMD_T (b_cmd_t) 
)
u0
(
  .cmd() 
);

endmodule
```

let parameter CNT=5, and compile again the error message
"Negative multiconcat multiplier" is disappear.
So it seems the value  `WIDTH = $bits(cmd.tag)` is 4 instead of 8.
But I expect the value should come from b_cmd_t

So I'm wondering is there anything wrong in this RTL code that I can not overwrite the packed struct successfully?

Comment: you have not shown your problem. What does it mean that "*it seems that WIDTH is 4*"? How do you know it? in which instance? Please provide a reproducible example. Otherwise your code looks more or less correct. BTW, there are no such thing as *package struct* you probably meant *packed struct*.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I modify the description to explain why I think the WIDTH is 4. And Yes I mean packed struct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The messages you saw are correct. Look at the instance from the error message:

```
 target#(4, a_cmd_t, , )
```

in the above `CNT == 4` and width of the tag in the *a_cmd_t* is 4 as well: `logic [3:0]     tag`

The expression `localparam ZERO_FILL_WIDTH = (WIDTH - CNT);` is evaluated to `0`, which is illegal in the following replicator: `{ZERO_FILL_WIDTH{1'b0}};`.

With the second issue (negative number) the problem is different. There is apparently a bug in vcs. For whatever reason vcs does not do correct job there and does not do correct override. It looks into a correct struct but does not pick up correct field and fails to recognize it width being 8. I suggest that you report it to synopsys.

However, if you get rid of localparams and use the following, it will work:

```
  wire [$bits(cmd.tag) - CNT -1:0] test;
  assign test = {$bits(cmd.tag) - CNT{1'b0}};
```

Comment: Yes, I think the second issue (negative number) may be a problem from synopsys VCS. I'm reporting this on solvnet and waiting for feedback. If there is any update I will reply here. Thank you for your workaround suggestion.  It's helpful.

Comment: I've report this issue through solvnet. And synopsys support team think it's a vcs compiler tool bug issue.

Comment: I reported it as well :-)